# Rails app hosted on HostMonster trying to access db as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

So this is my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: vollapp_test

# Avoid production credentials in the repository,
# instead read the configuration from the environment.
#
# Example:
#   mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase
#
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
```

On my production server, hosted by hostmonster i am getting a 500 error and the production log says `Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost')`. The weird thing about this is my DATABASE_URL doesnt even use 'root' as the user. 
I know this is in fact may be a duplicate but I have tried all the answers from all the other questions I found on this and none of them fit / work for me. rake db:migrate works fine for me. Honestly im stumped.

Comment: I'm not sure that `url` contains all the information needed to connect. You may have to break out the parameters separately. See: [example](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/database-yml-rails)

Comment: i actually broke out all the url information so that it included the information in the link you added and it still didn't work.

Comment: nevermind...I forgot to touch tmp/restart.txt to restart passenger....this worked. Wish i could find a way to put the info in the environment variable like the default was.

Comment: Ah, that's a constant gotcha. Rails will always adapt to changes to anything in `app/` or `config/routes.rb` when in development mode, but anything else requires the `restart.txt` trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to spell out the configuration parameters in full in addition to the URL method:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  username: username
  password: password
  host: hostname
  database: databasename
  url: <%+ ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
```

I hope they actually parse the `url` value in future versions of Rails because this seems to be a bit of duplicated effort.

Any changes to `config/database.yml` will require restarting your Rails process(es).